# Hibernate TABLE is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I receive this error

```
11:55:43,125 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] (MSC service thread 1-16) Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
11:55:43,215 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-16) org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ServerSettings is not mapped [from ServerSettings as ss]
11:55:43,215 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-16)   at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
11:55:43,215 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-16)   at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
11:55:43,216 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-16)   at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
```

When attempting to deploy my application.

My class is called ServerSettings.java - it looks like

```
static public ServerSettings GetServerSettings() throws Exception
{
    List retList = null;
    ServerSettings ss = null;
    try {
        Session hsession = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        retList = hsession.createQuery("from ServerSettings as ss").list();
        if (retList == null || retList.size() <= 0)
            return null;
        ss = (ServerSettings) retList.get(0);
    } 
    finally
    {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
    return ss;
```

our persistence.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">

  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <!-- <sproperty name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" /> -->
     <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> -->
  </properties>
```

We also have a hibernate.cfg.xml

```
   <session-factory>
      <property name="datasourceName">java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

   </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and a ServerSettings.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.mycompanyServerSettings" table="server_settings">
        <id name="serverSettingsID" type="integer" column="server_settings_id"> 
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <version  name="updateCounter" column="update_counter"/>
        <property name="changedDate" type="timestamp" column="changed_date"/>
        <property name="changedBy" type="string" column="changed_by"/>
        <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp" column="created_date"/>
        <property name="createdBy" type="string" column="created_by"/>
        <property name="status" type="string" column="status"/>

        <property name="defaultJmsQueueName" type="string" column="default_jms_queue_name"   />
        <property name="defaultJmsQueueURL" type="string" column="default_jms_queue_url"   />
        <property name="emailServer" type="string" column="email_server"   />
        <property name="emailFromAddress" type="string" column="email_from_address"   />
        <property name="emailUser" type="string" column="email_user"   />
        <property name="emailPassword" type="string" column="email_password"   />
        <property name="defaultJMSQueueID" type="string" column="default_jms_queue_id"   />
        <property name="useEncryption" type="integer" column="use_encryption"   />

</class>
```

Usually this error is caused when using table name instead of class name in hql - but that's not the case here.  Also this was working previously in JBoss AS5 - I'm moving it to JBoss AS7.  Any advice?

Comment: is that a typo on the class tag in your mapping. should be com.mycompany.ServerSettings.

Answer (score 3):

```
<class name="com.mycompanyServerSettings"
                          ^-- A dot is missing here
```

Moreover, the `ServerSettings.hbm.xml` isn't referenced in the main `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. You should have such an element in the `session-factory` element:

```
<mapping resource="com/mycompany/ServerSettings.hbm.xml"/>
```